# Как проверить массив, является ли он непрерывно возрастающим

Tags: javascript, массивы

Задание звучит так. "Реализуйте и экспортируйте по умолчанию функцию, которая проверяет, является ли переданная последовательность целых чисел возрастающей непрерывно (не имеющей пропусков чисел). Например, последовательность [4, 5, 6, 7] — непрерывная, а [0, 1, 3] — нет. Последовательность может начинаться с любого числа, главное условие — отсутствие пропусков чисел. Шаг последовательности равен 1. Последовательность из одного числа не может считаться возрастающей."

Вот мое решение, но оно проходит один тест и падает. Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста

```
const isContinuousSequence = (array) => {
  if (array.length === 1 || array.length === 0) {
    return false;
  }
  if (array[array.length - 1] <= array[array.length - 2]) {
    return false;
  }
  for (let i = 1; i < array.length - 1; i += 1) {
    if (array[i] < array[i - 1] || array[i - 1] === array[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  } return true;
};
export default isContinuousSequence;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас ряд ошибок в проверках.

Реализуйте фукнцию проверки последовательно и согласно условиям(например вы не проверяете, что разница между соседними элементами равна 1).

Ниже пример реализации данной фукнции

```js
const isContinuousSequence = (array) => {
  if (array.length < 2) return false; //Если меньше 2х элементов

  for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] - array[i-1] !== 1) return false; //Если разница не 1
  }
  return true; // успех
};

console.log(isContinuousSequence([1,2,3,4]))
console.log(isContinuousSequence([1,2,3,4,6]))
console.log(isContinuousSequence([5,6,7,8]))
console.log(isContinuousSequence([]))
console.log(isContinuousSequence([3]))
```

Comment: в чем смысл второго if?

Comment: @Grundy Случайно скопировался. Поправил. Он был из примера

Comment: Спасибо большое!)

Comment: @АлександрКурсаков, в одну строку `arr => arr.every((el, i, a)=> i && (el - a[i] == 1)`

Comment: @Grundy Проверку не проходит. Он же сравнивает текущий элемент с текущим и при пустом массиве true выдает

Comment: @Grundy результаты отличны от результатов SwaD. К примеру в первом массиве у вас `fasle`, а у SwaD `true`. А ещё вы забыли закрывающую скобку в конце.

Comment: @SwaD, да `i-1` надо :)

Comment: `arr => !arr.some((el, i, a)=> i && (el - a[i-1] != 1))` - так лучше :) хотя пустой массив все портит ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ сделаем вид, что пустой массив не будет передаваться :)

Comment: @Grundy на самом деле нет, т.к. some остановится после первого вернувшегося true, а every после первого false...

Comment: @Grundy `&& !!arr.length` :p

Comment: @SwaD, так это и надо, там условие тоже изменилось :) обрати внимание, что в цикле ты тоже делаешь `return` после первого `true` условия :)

Comment: @ΝNL993 это лишнее, да и смысла в `!!` нет в этом случае

Comment: @Grundy Взял обновление, да, сейчас отрабатывает(ну если пустой массив не брать в рассчет) :)

Comment: @Grundy `arr => arr.length > 2 ? !arr.some((el, i, a)=> i && (el - a[i-1] !== 1)) : false;` в одну строку с проверкой на пустой массив :)

Comment: @SwaD, вместо тернарника стоило `&&` использовать. и по идее надо `>1`. Но расчет был на то, чтобы просто один запрос к массиву был :)

Comment: @Grundy Да, точно, `> 1`. Мне кажется идея с одним обращением тут не получится, ибо в `some` сам массив полностью дергается при каждом `a[i-1]`. В целом, вся фукнция в строку красиво уместилась. Можно тернарник на `&&` заменить, посмотрел, работает.

Comment: @SwaD, что значит _сам массив полностью дергается при каждом a[i-1]_?

Comment: @Grundy на каждой итерации метода some передается текущий массив(`a`) в фукнцию колбэка, выбирается элемент с индексом `i-1`. Мне кажется, что назвать это 1 обращением к массиву не совсем верным

Comment: @SwaD, время доступа к элементу - константное - так что получение по индексу не влияет ни на что. Под одним обращением имелось ввиду одна функция проходящая по массиву.